# Why Ionic Ionic2 platform ready is taking very long time?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

**Why would ionic platform takes very long time to call ready function..??**

Please check, attached video link : https://youtu.be/AWncpv5rIgQ

**Please suggest solutions..**

```js
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  alert(1);
  if(this.splashScreen) {
    alert(2);
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(3);
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running your app in development mode it takes some time to fire the platform.ready() event since it has assertions and various necessary framework checks turned on.

Try running the app in production mode to speed up and optimize the start of your application

If you're in an ionic 2 app, you can enable this by doing the following,

**open src/app/main.ts**

Import enableProdMode from Angular 2 core

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
```

Then call the enableProdMode() function before bootstraping your module

```
enableProdMode();

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and now while running the app through cli try adding a flag like "--prod"

```
ionic run android --prod
```

In ionic 3.x, you don't have to enable anything in the code. you can simply run it using the cli command,

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

check this documentation from [angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/enableProdMode)

Hope that helps